# Xcode: 'shared' flag in manage schemes doesn't have an effect

Tags: ios, xcode, git

Here's what happened: I had to clone my git repo containing an Xcode project again in order to clean things up. I have a framework build with an aggregate scheme that relies on the other scheme to be called from CLI (`xcodebuild`). When I open the project in the new repo clone, the aggregate build fails, telling me `xcodebuild: error: The project 'FooProj_Framework' does not contain a scheme named 'FooProj_Framework' (even though that scheme clearly exists and works with the old repo clone). Googling this error all points towards the 'Shared' flag in the 'Manage Schemes' dialog. However, setting this for the scheme 'FooProj_Framework' still leads to the same error, and curiously, when closing Xcode and opening again the 'Shared' flag is gone again - so it doesn't persist. It looks to me like Xcode is confusing some storage for the new repo with the old one since the project names and filenames are the same. I've tried

1. cleaning the build first and
2. deleting all derived data for all projects in my organizer.

to no effect. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've found the problem. It was an combination of two issues:

- before checking in the last time, the schemes were not shared and I have `xcuserdata` in the gitignore.
- when trying to change the schemes to shared later, I had a silent problem with the ownership of my folder, so Xcode couldn't actually save when I closed the 'manage schemes' dialog. Helpfully, such an error is not reported by Xcode.

So the solution was just to solve the folder permission problem and add `FooProj_Framework.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/ to the git.